# How to get objects from two different tables that have a relationship to a third table using the related names in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let me explain. I have 2 tables which are child classes of another abstract table. The abstract table has a relationship to a model called `Foo`. The `related_name` is set dynamically. The code looks like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Parent(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(
        Foo,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related'
    )
    ...

    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ChildOne(Parent):
    ...

class ChildTwo(Parent):
    ...
```

Therefore, the related names become `'myapp_childone_related'`, and `'myapp_childtwo_related'`.

Now, lets say I want to call the `bar()` method of all the objects from the `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` model that is related to a `Foo` object. There is a catch though, I want to it from with a class method of the `Foo` model. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
 class Foo(models.Model):
     ...

     def call_bar(self):
         references = ('childone', 'childtwo')
         for ref in references:
             children = getattr(self, f'myapp_{ref}_related').all()
             for child in children:
                 child.bar()
```

This works fine, but honestly feels a bit hack-y, especially when dealing with more than two children classes. Is there a nicer, more Pythonic solution to this problem?

Edit: I decided not to mention previously that I wanted to call the `bar()` method from within a class method of the `Foo` model because I thought that it was unnecessary for this question. However, Daneil Roseman's answer suggested making a list of classes, which is a good solution, but it would not work within the class method, as the classes have not yet been defined at that point in the module. So mentioning that in this edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related_name is only syntactic sugar for performing a query from the related class itself. So you should just do this explicitly:

```
child_classes = [ChildOne, ChildTwo]
for child_class in child_classes:
    children = child_class.objects.filter(foo=foo)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[ChildOne, ChildTwo]`? As you seem to referring the class names in the list.

Comment: Ok sorry I decided not to mention a detail earlier. However, I have edited the question, and now, your solution would not work, because where I actually want to do this, the classes have not yet been defined.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter if those classes are defined after that method, as long as they are defined by the time the method is *called*,